# Express res.redirect() not doing anything

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I'm working on a Google OAuth flow with Express as a backend, and in part of my code I use `res.redirect()`. For some reason, it doesn't do anything at all when I view the route in my browser, not even print any errors.

When `console.log`ing the url, I get a full valid url like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?......
```

I tried removing the redirect code so it's just `res.redirect(url)`, and also tried various different codes. When I choose a code like 400, it displays a message like this:

```
Bad Request. Redirecting to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?......
```

I also tried `.end()` to end the request, but it throws an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'end' of undefined`.

Below is the portion of the code that handles generating an auth url and redirecting the user to it.

```
app.get('/url', (req, res) => {
  const url = /* generating url */
  res.redirect(301, url)
})
```

I would expect it to redirect me to the site so I could authorize my app, but instead it just displays an empty page.

EDIT: For some reason, it's actually sending a 200 OK response!

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT 2: And no, I'm not using AJAX.

EDIT 3: This route is actually inside an `express.Router()`, if that matters.

EDIT 4: Here's some more code:

```
// server.js

import express from 'express'
import handler from './handler'

const app = express()
app.use('/auth', handler)
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('> Ready on port 4000'))
```

```
// handler.js

import { Router } from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'

const router = Router()
router.use(bodyParser.json())
router.use(cookieParser())

router.get('/url', (req, res) => {
  const url = /* generating url */
  res.redirect(301, url)
})

// Other routes

export default router
```

Comment: Is the request being sent by an Ajax call from Javascript in the browser?  If so, redirects to an ajax call don't cause the browser to change the page at all.  It's up to the receiving Javascript to do something useful with the redirect.

Comment: @jfriend00 Nope! In fact, for testing I was directly visiting the site in my browser.

Comment: You can confirm it's definitely hitting that route? Because I'm guessing it isn't, do you happen to have a catch all route?

Comment: @James I can confirm it is, I have it logging to the console for debugging purposes.

Comment: @UnknownUser I take it you've tried redirecting to an obvious URL (e.g. Google) to test?

Comment: @James Yep, of course. Still nothing.

Comment: @UnknownUser please show your routing setup before & after this particular route because the behaviour you are seeing clearly isn't correct.

Comment: @James I updated the question. Also, StackOverflow wants us to move this discussion to chat. Should I do what it wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is super obvious and I'm not sure why I didn't realize earlier. After hours of sweat and tears, I present to you the answer:

It was all a problem with [the development proxy I was using](https://github.com/zeit/micro-proxy). Apparently it doesn't support redirects, so I had to write my own. Works fine now.

Comment: that url is 404ing